SPL-TOKEN || SPL-TOKEN-GROUP || CODECS 2.0.0-preview.4 ->> 2.0.0-rc.1 BREAKING CHANGE
Currently the NPM package for spl-token is shipping with spl-token-group 0.0.5
spl-token-group 0.0.5 uses codecs 2.0.0-preview.4
the lastest release dependencies with codecs 2.0.0-rc.1
I am running into runtime issues because of the conflict in codecs between these packages.
Is there an update needed to be pushed to spl-token that will fix this to align with the update from 2 days ago with the rest of the packages?

The spl-token package is just out of date, feel free to create an issue at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues to ask about publishing the next version
